# Is it necessary to book an airport-to-private shuttle in advance?

Tags: airport-transfer, new-york-city, bookings, ewr

We will be landing in Newark airport (New York).

I know there are door-to-door services such as SuperShuttle that offer to book online. Is there a point to it? Would we skip a line? Save money?

Answer (score 1):

We didn't book [Newark Airport Express](http://www.coachusa.com/olympia/ss.newarkairport.asp) in advance (I don't know, if it's even possible) and did not have to wait. When we got back to EWR a few days later, we had to wait for one bus, because the first one was already full.

Newark Airport Express stops at Grand Central Station, Bryant Park and Port Authority Bus Terminal.

Comment: Newark Airport Express is a bug. I was talking about door-to-door shuttle services.

Comment: Sorry, did not read your questions thoroughly.